# What happens if program with same name exists in different locations in Windows PATH?

Tags: windows, environment-variables, path

When we type a command into a terminal and press enter, it searches for the current directory first and not finding anything there it searches ever PATH and sees if something of that name exists anywhere in there. If it finds something there, it will run it. If it does not find anything there, it shall output an error message. Is this correct?

If this is so, what happens if something exists in the current directory that has same name in the PATH or if there are two PATH entries that contain program of same name (in different locations of course). How are such conflicts solved?

Answer (score 2):

Windows searches the path from first entry to last. So if a program exists in 2 folders, and both folders are also listed in the `PATH` environment, command prompt will execute the following mechanism:

You run `program.exe`

1. Is program.exe located in the current folder?
2. Is program.exe located in the 1st entry in `%PATH%`?
3. Is program.exe located in the 2nd entry in `%PATH%`?

And will go so on.

It will check each folder in the `%PATH%` until either `program.exe` was found or not at all.

If it isn't found at this stage, you get an error that the program could not be located, and that you have to check your spelling.

So the more to the left of a `%PATH%` string a folder is, the higher its priority, but if the program exists in the current folder, `%PATH%` is not checked at all.